# Question regarding the mean of independently (not identically ) distributed random variables?

Tags: summation, random-variables, expectation

Hi i have the following question which may be a simple question for majority of the people. But i need to know the difference clearly ..

Let $X_1 ,...X_n$ be independently distributed (not identically) random variables with distribution of $ ~ uniform [0,n]$ .

I need to find the expectation of $ \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$

Since the distribution is $uniform$ , $E(X_k)= n/2$ . So $E(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n E(X_k) $ = $\sum_{k=1}^n n/2$ .

Since the variables are only independently distributed, can i further simplify to $(n* n/2 )$  or do i need to stop from $\sum_{k=1}^n n/2$.

Also if the variables are $IID$ , then  is $E(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k) = n* n/2 = n^2/2  $ ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you say they are **not** identically distributed, then that the distribution is $uniform[0,n]$?  That is identically distributed.

Comment: @RobertIsrael the question says nothing about identical distributed. It says only independently distributed

Comment: You are over thinking!! $\sum_{k=1}^nc=nc$ when $c$ is constant.

Comment: @Statlover : Related to Robert's comment: Can you give an example of two random variables $A, B$ that are both uniformly distributed over $[0,2]$ but that are _not_ identically distributed?  (This is similar to finding an example of two distinct colors that are both green).